# How to measure the speed of a vehicle using the sound of the engine?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, acoustics, everyday-life, home-experiment

While I was taking the bus a few days ago, I came across an interesting thought: Assuming an ***ideal*** vehicle with a single cylinder engine,is it possible to measure the speed of the vehicle by the graph of the sound produced by the engine ? I hope to extrapolate the situation to a realistic scenario soon.

**In the ideal case I am measuring sitting inside the vehicle, under ideal weather conditions on a smooth straight stretch of road and the gear is not being changed.**

Comment: this might be of interest http://www.ymec.com/hp/signal2/car1.htm

Comment: As mentioned in an answer, frequency is probably your best option.  If you need to use sound intensity, be aware that air flow will contribute a lot of noise at higher speeds.  Confounding factors would include: is it a calm or windy day? are the car windows up or down? Is the road surface smooth or rough?

Comment: I would expect the frequency (or some spectral measurement) of the sound to correlate better with vehicle speed than the intensity.

Comment: How would you do the experiment? Do you really have a vehicle with one cylinder and fixed gear?

Comment: @nasu, I don't intend to use a machine of such a sort, but after all complex phenomena are usually modelled after simple idealizations ,right? I intended to ask the question in such a spirit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually figure out rpm of the engine from its sound, which closely relates to the velocity of the vehicle. A video in Youtube ([link](https://youtu.be/DXfw-sIQUws)) explains this fairly well.

The sound you hear from an engine is mainly due to the rhythmic explosions that happen inside the combustion chamber of the piston which rapidly pushes the fuel gases out of the exhaust. There are other noises due to the vibration of several parts of the vehicle, but the 'Dominant frequency' you hear as the engine runs is due to the above reason.

[image: single cylinder]

From the above illustration, you can see that for each explosion in the piston, the axle rotates a complete revolution. Or in other words, the time period of explosions in the piston is equal to that of revolution of the wheel.

Suppose you find the dominant frequency to be $600Hz$. You know that there are $100$ explosions in a second. So you would have $600$ revolutions of the wheel in one second. This gives the angular speed to be $\frac{600}{60}$= $10rpm$.

You can find out the velocity ( when wheels are not slipping) if you know the gear ratios and radius of vehicle's tyres.

It would be a very simple and elegant way to find out the velocity of the vehicle you are travelling in, using just your phone's microphone!

Answer (score 2):

Sound intensity will vary as the vehicle moves, as it depends on how far away it is. Hence that is not useful for working out vehicle speed.

It's should be possible to use frequency, as the engine has a beat that indicates how fast it's running and hence, as there's only one gear, how fast the car is going. It might need some Fourier analysis to extract that frequency from the engine noise though.

Comment: I shall update the question with the added assumption that i am observing, sitting inside the vehicle

Comment: From inside the vehicle, my second paragraph is still valid. Using sound intensity inside is probably still impossible. Volume increases under heavy acceleration, but speed does not affect it much.

Answer (score 1):

The sound frequency spectrum should correlate with velocity. However the correlation will depend on the vehicle type and the gear, tyre shape (type, pressure). You will have to deal with non-correlating noise from background, engine wear, loose parts or cargo, road condition, your location and speed with respect to the vehicle. This rapidly gets quite complex for a simple speed measurement.

Answer (score 0):

There will probably not be a direct, linear correlation between sound intensity and vehicle speed.  Sound intensity will depend on wind direction, humidity, air pressure, air temperature, the vehicle's shape, the texture of the road and tires, and the engine sound.  Engine sound will depend on the air/fuel mixture.

However, if all factors other than vehicle speed are kept constant, it should be possible to take sound intensity measurements at various speeds and draw a correlation between sound intensity and vehicle speed.

Comment: I am really sorry, but I forgot to inform prior to removing "intensity" from sound intensity in the question